# Why the result of Exists function use == and != is not opposite?

Tags: c#, arrays, string, exists

```
string input = "1234";
string[] array = { "0", "1", "2", "3", "4", "5", "6", "7", "8", "9" };

bool in_N1 = Array.Exists(array, x => x == input.Substring(0, 1));
bool in_N2 = Array.Exists(array, x => x == input.Substring(1, 1));
bool in_N3 = Array.Exists(array, x => x == input.Substring(2, 1));
bool in_N4 = Array.Exists(array, x => x == input.Substring(3, 1));

Console.WriteLine(input.Substring(0, 1) + in_N1);
Console.WriteLine(input.Substring(1, 1) + in_N2);
Console.WriteLine(input.Substring(2, 1) + in_N3);
Console.WriteLine(input.Substring(3, 1) + in_N4);

bool in_N5 = Array.Exists(array, x => x != input.Substring(0, 1));
bool in_N6 = Array.Exists(array, x => x != input.Substring(1, 1));
bool in_N7 = Array.Exists(array, x => x != input.Substring(2, 1));
bool in_N8 = Array.Exists(array, x => x != input.Substring(3, 1));

Console.WriteLine(input.Substring(0, 1) + in_N5);
Console.WriteLine(input.Substring(1, 1) + in_N6);
Console.WriteLine(input.Substring(2, 1) + in_N7);
Console.WriteLine(input.Substring(3, 1) + in_N8);

//the result I got
1True
2True
3True
4True
1True
2True
3True
4True
```

ps.I also tried input with symbols like "+" or + "-" , the bool result is the same as what I thought. But if I input numbers there is the problem, I am confused...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let's do a high-level English version of what you're asking C# to evaluate..

> a) Dear C#, here are some numbers: 1,2,3,4. Does there exist any number in that set that is EQUAL to 1?

Yes

> b) Dear C#, here are some numbers: 1,2,3,4. Does there exist any number in that set that is NOT EQUAL to 1?

Yes

---

In the first case, C# says yes because 1 is equal to 1. In the second case C# says yes because 2 is not equal to 1

Comment: Thanks for your answer!  So,  
bool in_N1 = Array.Exists(array, x => x == 1);  
It means "if 1 exists in the Array.  

bool in_N5 = Array.Exists(array, x => x != 1);  
It means "if any other numbers is not equal to 1, maybe 2, or 3(even  other symbols), exists in the Array?  
in other words, if I put only one element "1" in the Array, the != result will be false, right?

Comment: *if I put only one element "1" in the Array, the != result will be false, right?* - correct. You could also put multiple "1" in the array, like `new[]{"1","1","1","1"}` - for this too the statement "there exists an element that is not equal to `"1"`" is false

Comment: Probably also worth noting that these days we would perhaps say `numbers.Any(n => n != "1")` which makes it a bit easier to read/reason about in my opinion: *"for all `numbers` we can find Any number `n` that is not equal to "1""*